# Show Database in listbox

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, winforms, sqlite

**i want to show User name list form Database (sqlite) and this is my code**

when i run the program nothing show

```
private void UserList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connectionString conn = new connectionString();
        string query = "SELECT  Username FROM Userdata";
        SQLiteCommand test = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn.myconnection);
       var non = test.ExecuteReader();
        foreach (var USR in non)
        {
            UserList.Items.Add(USR);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `SQLiteDataReader` to read the result of a command executed against a SQLite database.

You can refer to the following demo.

```
SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite");
m_dbConnection.Open();

SQLiteCommand sqlCom = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT Username FROM Userdata", m_dbConnection);
SQLiteDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();

while (sqlDataReader.Read())
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(sqlDataReader.GetValue(0));
}

m_dbConnection.Close();
```